# Using sympy to sum over a range of symbols

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Consider two sets i,j which both have `m` elements. Say we have an expression which describes a sum of terms. Each term can be described as a product of an element of i and j. Now, I would like to sum over each element of j, where each element has the range `[i1,i2,...,im]`.

In the context of python & sympy, this is difficult since sympy's [Sum](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html?highlight=sum#sympy.concrete.summations.Sum) describes the summation variable with `(symbol,start,stop)`, which assume integer steps.

To demonstrate what I mean, consider the following code:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> i = symbols('i1,i2,i3,i4') # for the case m = 4
>>> j = symbols('j1,j2,j3,j4')
```

Here I use permutations to setup the expression:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations as perm
>>> c = list(perm(range(4),2))
>>> a,b = c[0]
>>> expr = i[a]*j[b]
>>> for a,b in c[1:]:
>>>     expr += i[a]*j[b]
>>> print(expr)
i1*j2 + i1*j3 + i1*j4 + i2*j1 + i2*j3 + i2*j4 + i3*j1 + i3*j2 + i3*j4 + i4*j1 + i4*j2 + i4*j3
```

Now, using Sum over each `j` with range of `i`. It would be ideal if I could write one of the following:

```
>>> s = Sum(expr,(j,i))
>>> s = Sum(expr,(j1,i),(j2,i),...,(jm,i))
```

But that's not canonical with the sympy documentation. Are there any other methods which can be used to solve this problem?

**Edit:**
In this post, I tried to isolate the problem by only using elements `i`,`j` in `expr`. The full context problem is where `expr` is a sum of Kronecker Delta functions of `i`,`j` and using a sum over index set `j`, where each element of `j` has range `i`. For example:

```
>>> from sympy import KroneckerDelta as KD
>>> expr = KD(i[0],j[1]) # Only doing j[1] to reduce clutter
>>> print(expr)
KroneckerDelta(i1,j2)
>>> s = Sum(expr,(j[1],i)).doit() 
>>> print(s)
# Desired output to look like:
1 + KroneckerDelta(i1,i2) + KroneckerDelta(i1,i3) + KroneckerDelta(i1,i4)
```

This is the reason for which I phrased my question as: summing over each element of `j` with range `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`IndexedBase` can act as a symbolic, integer-indexed array:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import k,l
>>> i,j = map(IndexedBase,'ij')
>>> Sum(i[k]*j[l],(k,1,2),(l,1,2)).doit().expand()
i[1]*j[1] + i[1]*j[2] + i[2]*j[1] + i[2]*j[2]
>>> Sum(Piecewise((i[k]*j[l],Ne(k,l)),(0,True)),(k,1,2),(l,1,2)).doit()
i[1]*j[2] + i[2]*j[1]
```

It's not clear whether you want the cross terms when the indicices are the same, so both versions are shown.

Comment: missing `k, l = symbols('k l')`

Comment: @smichr This is not exactly the problem I'm trying to describe, but maybe I'm unclear. I will update the post to add some more clarity on the expected output.

Comment: `Sum(KroneckerDelta(i[k],i[l]),(k,2,2),(l,1,4)).doit()` gives your desired (edited) output assuming you let `j=i` (since no `j` appears in your output.